# Probability of Normal estimations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have this problem:

> Two independent estimates of fire damage in a building are made. Each estimate is assumed with a Normal distribution of mean $10b$ and variance $b^2$.

I am asked to calculate the probability that the first estimate is at least $20\%$ greater than the second estimate.

So I tried the following: 
Let $X_1$ be the random variable of the first estimate and $X_2$ if the second, then
$P(X_1\geq1.2X_2)=P\left(\frac{X_1}{X_2}\geq1.2\right)$. Let $Z=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$. So I need to find how $Z$ is distributed.

I know that $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f_{X_1}(zx_2)f_{X_2}(x_2)}\,dx_2$ and doing some math I arrive to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi b^2 }}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac{zx_2-10b}{\sigma }}\right)^{2}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi b^2 }}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac{x_2-10b}{\sigma }}\right)^{2}}\,dx_2$$

But I don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Instead of dividing the inequality, try to subtract the right hand side from the left hand side. A linear combination of independent normally distributed random variables is normal.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment** in Answer format for simplicity of formatting.
Do what @Stacker says for a formal answer. Informally,
a simulation shows that the answer is very nearly $0.1.$
(Without loss of generality, let $b = 1.)$

```
set.seed(431)
x = rnorm(10^6, 10, 1)
y = rnorm(10^6, 10, 1)
mean(x > 1.2*y)
[1] 0.100114
```

It is permitted to answer your own question.
Start by finding $E(X - 1.2Y) = -2,$ where $X$ and $Y$
are the two estimates. Then find $Var(X - 1.2Y).$ And SD. What is the normal distribution of $W = X-2Y?$ Standardize and find probability.